# start Date should currentDate in Ionic2 dateTime

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to set current date as start date of datetime in Ionic2.
User should not be able to select yesterday or previous date.

This is my code.

```
 <ion-datetime class="date-input-box" min ="2017-04-05" displayFormat="MM/DD/YY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="event.date"(ionChange)="timeChange()">
```

I have seen a plunker in Ionic1. this works fine.
but i want this in ionic2

http://embed.plnkr.co/mIEnslYTrSSiCROx6qsH/preview

This is almost same thing as my requirement.but this is in angular1.

I have also tried this

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-date-picker-min-max-date/74492

Comment: i have tried to add min date , but this does not work for me, @Ajk_P i also edited my question.

Comment: @Ajk_P that does not work. give error.if we use without spaces. 
that is date and in date format.

Comment: EXCEPTION!! Please tell engineering how did you do this.Error: Error in ./ProposalConfirmDateModalPage class ProposalConfirmDateModalPage - inline template:35:12 caused by: Cannot read property 'year' of null @Ajk_P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140007/discussion-between-muhammad-nadeem-and-ajk-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine.

[image]

**Play with** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lE4VXp?p=preview)

**.html**

```
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YY" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY" min="2017-04-05" 
  max="2020-10-31" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
  </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**.ts**

```
 myDate="2017-04-05T17:48:20.084Z";
```

Comment: it's not a problem.you can play with my `plunker` above @Ajk_P

Comment: @Sampath thanks for figure out. you solved my issue.

Comment: It's a pleasure :)